# How to put new element depending on position on masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

So I have this page that uses jQuery masonry. It's a two column page and what I want to do is make a div appear on the divisions that appear on the left side and a different div on the ones that appear on the right side.

```
┌---------------------------------┐#content
| ┌-------------┐ ┌-------------┐ |
| |          [A]| |[B]          | |
| |             | |             | |             
| |             | |             | |
| └-------------┘ |             | |
| ┌-------------┐ |             | |
| |          [A]| |             | | 
| |             | |             | |
| |             | └-------------┘ |
| └-------------┘ ┌-------------┐ |                 
|                 |[B]          | |
|                 |             | |
|                 |             | |
|                 └-------------┘ |
└---------------------------------┘
```

So there, there's a relatively positioned div(.post) that uses masonry inside another div(#content). What I want to do is make div "A" appear only on the .post div that goes to the left and div "B" appear only on the .post divs that appear on the right.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have only two columns, so I would use jQuery to compare `$('#content').left()` and `$('.post').left()`. If they are the same (or the same + some padding if you use it on `#content`), the `.post` is of type A. If they are different, the post is of type B.

This will allow you to style the `<div>`s differently or inject different content into them.